# How do i put the table number and caption on same line in latex

Tags: tables, formatting, captions, tabularx

I have a table with code and a table like this:

```
\begin{table*}[!htp]
  \begin{center}
  \captionsetup[table]{format=plain,labelformat=simple,labelsep=period}
  \captionof*{table} {My caption for table.}
  \label{Tab:table_2}
    \begin{tabular}
      Table
     \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table*}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: the table number and caption on two line in latex]]

**Question:** How do I put the table number and caption on same line in LaTeX?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  If I make a guess at how to complete your code, I don't get the result that you claim (it's always helpful to have a MWE).  Regardless, `\captionof` is for putting a table inside something that doesn't look like a `table`.  Since you're already in a `table*`, have you tried using `\caption` without the `of`?  That made a change with my completion of your code.

Comment: The caption shown in your screenshot would appear to have nothing to do with the setup instructions `\captionsetup[table]{format=plain, labelformat=simple, labelsep=period}`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you after for something like this:

[image]

As already mentioned in comment below your query, your code is unnecessary complicated and not works as you desired:

- instead `center` environment (which insert additional vertical space around `table` environment) is better to use command `\centering
- since table caption is inside `table` environment for caption you can (and should) use simple `\caption` command
- settings for table caption should be in the document preamble (that all table captions will have the same formatting). There it will works as desired.
- With your code fragment inserted in `article` document I can't reproduce your problem.
- Considering above, table code is:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{format=plain,labelformat=simple,labelsep=period}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[!htp]
    \centering
\caption{My caption for table.}
\label{Tab:table_2}
\begin{tabular}{c}
    \hline
Table contents Table contents Table contents Table contents \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```